# "Unexpected operator" from [ $var -eq 1 ]

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am using this conditional in my bash script

```
if [ $USE_TEST -eq 1 ]; then
echo "Hello"
fi
```

where i pass `USE_TEST` as an environment variable.

If i pass env variable then shell executes ok but if i don't have that variable then i get this

```
[: -eq: unexpected operator
```

How can i fix that

Comment: Looks like `$USE_TEST ` is undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of those matter where quotes are important; when $USE_TEST is not defined, your statement expands to:

```
if [ -eq 1 ]; then
```

The common fix:

```
if [ "$USE_TEST" -eq 1 ]; then
```

...though that would also imply switching to a string comparison, because `-eq` will break with an empty string:

```
if [ "$USE_TEST" = 1 ]; then
```

But you may also consider using `[[` (which is a bash builtin) or `${USE_TEST:-0}` (which specifies a default value).

Comment: Another common solution is `${USE_TEST?}`, which generates an error and aborts the script if the variable is undefined.  Or `${USE_TEST:?}` which also aborts if the variable expands to the empty string.

Comment: if i use [[ then what will be syntax.   is thi sok [[ $USE_TEST -eq 1 ]]

Answer (score 1):

Assign default value (e.g. 0) to aviod an empty variable:

```
if [ ${USE_TEST:=0} -eq 1 ]; then
```

From `man bash`:

> `${parameter:=word}`: Assign Default Values.  If parameter is unset or null, the expansion of word is assigned to parameter.  The value of parameter is then substituted.

Comment: will `${USE_TEST:=0}` work inside makefile as well i mean   `VAR1=${USE_POSTGRES:=0}` (inside makefile)

Comment: @user3214546: You'd have to be very careful in a `makefile`.  `${USE_POSTGRES:=0}` has meaning to `make`, but it doesn't have the same meaning as in shell.  You'd probably use `$${USE_POSTGRES:=0}` in a shell fragment in a `makefile`; you can't really do what you want in a `make` macro definition, I think.  Or not without using GNU `make` extensions.

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is a boolean value, which is either 1 or 0, and the default is 0 if it is not defined.  In this case you can use a special bash syntax:

```
if (( USE_TEST ));
    echo "using test"
fi
```

The "(" parentheses are used for numerical values.  The dollar sign may be omitted in this case.

Comment: if i use this , do i need to define 0 default value or it can work without defining default 0 value

Comment: The number will be tested for truth similar to how C and some other programming languages operate.  0 is false, other numbers are true.  Non-digit strings will be converted to numbers, in most cases yielding 0, i.e. false. In particular, the empty string (and undefined variables) will be false.